# Tridion 2013 SP1 Component with large text content gives undefined error in General Tab

Tags: 2013-sp1

Tridion Component with large text content gives undefined error in General Tab. Source and other tabs load fine. I see following error in browser console.

> Uncaught Error: Object should be an element node.
>           at Object.Tridion.Utils.Assert.raiseError (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.11_.js:4)
>           at Object.Tridion.Utils.Assert.isElement (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.11_.js:4)
>           at Object.Tridion.ControlBase (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.11_.js:47)
>           at Tridion.FieldBuilder.FieldsContainer.addInterface (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.11_.js:9)
>           at new Tridion.FieldBuilder.FieldsContainer (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.11_.js:168)
>           at Tridion.FieldBuilder.doLoad (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.11_.js:167)
>           at coreresource_v7.1.0.66.11_.js:1

Structure of Component is like this:

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:034eeef7-86ca-4264-9d04-b18f90cc0de1">
<redirects>
    <from>source1</from>
    <to>target1</to>
    <code>301</code>
</redirects>
<redirects>
    <from>source2</from>
    <to>target2</to>
    <code>301</code>
</redirects>
.....
.....
</Content>
```

If I reduce the number of redirects it starts rendering properly.
Do I need to make any changes in Tridion CMS configuration? If yes can somebody please provide the configuration file name, path and what changes will be required?

Comment: You should check if IIS is rejecting the request due to length. On a default installation, that wouldn't be the case and you can store any length of data in a text field -- but it's possible that someone/something changed the settings to block large requests.

Comment: Also, check your Event Viewer for warnings from ASP.NET -- you might be getting an error on the server for a request that is expected to return XML or JSON and therefore isn't handled properly.